# How do I build a view of menu items?

Tags: views, 8

#### Scenario

- "landing page" content type, with node 1 at path node/1
- corresponding menu item A (with path node/1)
- children menu items of this menu item, B, C, D (with arbitrary paths http://google.com, zee/bang, and node/1234)

#### Objective

- Build a view which displays on node/1, whose results are links B, C, and D.

In Drupal 7, i would have used https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views to accomplish this.

How best to achieve this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I think D8 is too initial state to have a contrib solution for something "custom" like this. Personally, I would leave Views, and going instead:

1. Set up a route to a controller
2. In controller inject your own custom services and return the results in twig.
3. In your own service, inject any other service you need and to the business logic here.